# Java, filling Object[][] array with data

Tags: java, oop, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to fill an `Object[][]` array with data from my Object Class. However im having problems filling the array. Below is what I am trying to do to fill the `Object[][] data`. at the moment the returned data variable cannot be seen by the method. I have tried removing the method and filling the array where `rows` in declared but cannot because there is a for loop.

Am I currently filling the `object[][]` array correctly?

```
 public class CustomersDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {
    private CustomerList customers = new CustomerList();
    Object rows[][] = getData();

    public Object[][] getData() {
       customers = dataManager.getUserData();
       int size = customers.size();
       Customer customer = new Customer();

       for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           customer = customers.getCustomerAt(i);
           Object [][] data = { 
           { Integer.toString(customer.getCustomerID()), customer.getfName(), customer.getlName() } };
       }

       return data;
    }
 }
```

Further doing this method of creating the array outside the loop causes an 'empty statement message' by the compiler and it says it 'requires line ends `;` after the `.get` statements':

```
 public Object[][] getData() {
    customers = dataManager.getUserData();
    int size = customers.size();
    Customer customer;

    Object [][] data;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        customer = customers.getCustomerAt(i);
        data = { 
        { Integer.toString(customer.getCustomerID()), customer.getfName(), customer.getlName() } };
    }

    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not doing it properly.

In your code, you're declaring an array INSIDE `for` loop, which means that after the loop, the array doesn't exist anymore. That's why you can't return `data` - it simply does not exist.

More about scope and lifetime of variables you can read there: http://www.c4learn.com/javaprogramming/the-scope-and-lifetime-of-variables-in-java-programming-language/

What you want to do is to declare array outside the loop:

```
Object [][] data;
for(int i; i < size; i++) {
   // Filling data array
}
return data;
```

Next thing is that if you want to use an array, you should initialize it first:

```
Object [][] data = new Object [size][3];
```

Then you can fill it in `for` loop, like this:

```
for(int i; i < size; i++) {
   customer = customers.getCustomerAt(i);
   data[i][0] = Integer.toString(customer.getCustomerID());
   data[i][1] = customer.getfName();
   data[i][2] = customer.getlName();
}
```

Comment: An array created inside the for-loop will exist outside as long as the variable is declared outside. So that's not the problem here. But I agree that's not what you want most of the time.

Comment: Of course I meant declaring a variable inside a for loop, what he had done in his code. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I see the problem I had. All works as expected now.

Answer (score 2):

You have to allocate the array in two times. Once for the rows, and after once per row.

```
Object[][] data = new Object[size];
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   customer = customers.getCustomerAt(i);
   data[i] =
      new Object[]{
         Integer.toString(customer.getCustomerID()),
         customer.getfName(),
         customer.getlName()
      };
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use a 2 dimensional Array than you must define the size of the Array first (also if it is a n dimensional Array!)

See this content to get some clarification:

http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/arrays-2D.html

It seems to me like you only have one size Parameter for the Array, so I would use a normal Array instead of a 2 dimensional one.

I would do something like this:

```
public Object[] getData() {
   customers = dataManager.getUserData();
   int size = customers.size();
   Object[] result = new Object[size];
   Customer customer;

   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       customer = customers.getCustomerAt(i);
       result[i] = { 
       { Integer.toString(customer.getCustomerID()), customer.getfName(), customer.getlName() } };
   }

   return data;
}
```

If you have to use a 2 dimensional Object Array, than you have to define the second size dimension and fill the array like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeDimOne; i++) {
    for(int k = 0; k < sizeDimTwo; k++) {
          result[i][k] = { { Integer.toString(customer.getCustomerID()), customer.getfName(), customer.getlName() } }; 
    }
}
```

Hope this is helpful.